# Java Socket fast reconnect

Tags: java, performance, sockets, connect, reset

I am facing a little problem with sockets.

This method takes about 100ms or even more, depends on the server.
socket.connect(dest);

Then I am communicating through DataInput/Output streams to a sofisticated software, so there is query phase, handshake phase, login request phase etc.

Is there any way I can "reset" the datastream from handshake phase so the server forgets everything and the socket would be again in the first phase without doing socket.connect(dest); again ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which protocol are you using? Are you using some sort of authentication? Where is your endpoint? Which enviroment are you using (language, etc.)? It'd be nice if you'd give some code examples too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is entirely protocol dependent, it has nothing to do with sockets per se.

Comment: And this is not an answer aswell.

Comment: Actually I think that 'it depends' is the right answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing stopping you from passing as many messages back and forth through a socket; except maybe *your* protocol (or the lack of a clearly defined one) if it doesn't indicate where a message starts/ends.

When using a DataInput/OutputStream you could just define a Message class containing whatever data and both sides would just run in an infinite loop reading a Message, processing and possibly generating a response message.